# Why does this MySQL query never execute when a nearly identical query works fine?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector

The query in question:

```
    SELECT np.name AS name_trips, 
        s.station_name AS station_name, 
        np.id AS id, 
        COUNT(*) AS num_trips, 
        COUNT(NULLIF(np.start_end, 'Start')) AS num_start, 
        COUNT(NULLIF(np.start_end, 'End')) AS num_end
    FROM name_id_pairs np
    JOIN stations s ON np.id=s.station_id
    WHERE id IN(2498,3794)
    GROUP BY name, id
    ORDER BY id, num_trips DESC;
```

My other query which works every time is

```
    SELECT np.name AS name_trips, 
        s.station_name AS station_name, 
        np.id AS id, 
        COUNT(*) AS num_trips, 
        COUNT(NULLIF(np.start_end, 'Start')) AS num_start, 
        COUNT(NULLIF(np.start_end, 'End')) AS num_end
    FROM name_id_pairs np
    JOIN stations s ON np.id=s.station_id
    WHERE id IN(
        SELECT id
        FROM name_id_pairs 
        GROUP BY id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name)>1)
    GROUP BY name, id
    ORDER BY id, num_trips DESC;
```

The only difference between these queries is the WHERE clause, so why is the one with a sub query consistently completing within a few seconds, while `WHERE id IN(2498,3794)` will continue to execute until I restart the server.

Both queries are selecting from the same view

```
    CREATE VIEW name_id_pairs AS
    SELECT checkout_station_name AS name, checkout_station_id AS id, "Start" AS start_end
    FROM trips
    UNION ALL
    SELECT return_station_name AS name, return_station_id AS id, "End" AS start_end
    FROM trips;
```

I realize views can be bad for performance in MySQL, but if both queries are using the same view, I don't see how it could only be effecting the performance of one of them.

All of the queries were executed through python with the MySQL connector.

Since the only difference between the queries is the where clause, I tried  a few different versions of it but none of them executed correctly. I tried replacing the list with `WHERE id = 2498 OR id = 3794` but that didn't change anything. I also tried replacing id with the equivalent s.station_id or np.id, but the query still never executed.

Comment: Both queries are incorrect. Incomplete GROUP BY. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and fix the queries. Also - add table name/alias to EACH column name.

Answer (score 0):

Please qualify every column with the table it in.  `id`, for example, confuses me; it seems to be in all 3 tables.  But which is which?  *Maybe* this is the root of your problem.

Beware of `COUNTs` in a `JOIN` -- the `JOIN` happens first.  This may lead to an inflated count.

In general, `IN ( SELECT ... )` is inefficient.  It is better to use `JOIN` or `EXISTS`.  (I'm surprised that the `IN` was faster.)

I'm puzzled by the logic of `GROUP BY id` but looking for dup `name`.  Can you show a small amount of data to give me a feel for what is going on?

To answer your question, we need to see `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for each query.

Comment: I think Akina hit the nail on the head with the incomplete GROUP BY. I moved my aggregates into a sub query before joining the stations table and that fixed the issue.

Comment: Now check your results -- especially check for inflated COUNTs.